# Installation process of Apache Nutch in Ubuntu 16.04 , hadoop 2.6 already installed

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, software-installation, hadoop, solr

What is the correct compatible format of Apache Nutch for Ubuntu 16.04 and hadoop 2.6 ? What is the installation process ?